# Getting text around a specific element reference

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, regex

Having an HTML snippet like this:

```
<p>Lorem ipsum <mark>dolor</mark> sit amet. <mark>Lorem</mark> ipsum again
   and <mark>dolor</mark></p>
```

I can select the `<mark>` elements using `$("mark")`. I want to get a list of strings representing the `mark`ed word and 5 characters on the left side and 5 characters in the right side and prefix and suffix the strings with `[...]`.

For this example it would be:

```
[
   "[...] psum dolor sit [...]",
   "[...] met. Lorem ipsu [...]",
   "[...] and dolor [...]",
]
```

Currently I'm something like this:

```js
var $highlightMarks = $("mark");
var results = [];

for (var i = 0; i < $highlightMarks.length; ++i) {
  var $c = $highlightMarks.eq(i);
  var text = $c.parent().text().trim().replace(/\n/g, " ");
  var indexStart = new RegExp($c.html(), "gim").exec(text).index;
  text = "[...] " + text.substring(indexStart - 5, $c.html().length + indexStart + 5) + " [...]";
  results.push(text);
}

alert(JSON.stringify(results))
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>Lorem ipsum <mark>dolor</mark> sit amet. <mark>Lorem</mark> ipsum again and <mark>dolor</mark>.</p>
```

But this fails when two words are the same in the same paragraph (in this example: the `dolor` case).

Instead of showing `psum dolor sit` at the end of the array, it should be `and dolor.`.

So, having a reference to the `<mark>` element, what's the correct way to get some text on the right side and some text on the left side?

Comment: What exactly should be the output?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a two steps bulletproof implementation (counterexamples are welcomed) using only regex .

*Its greatest virtue is to work independently from a tag container (just like the `<p>...</p>` to extract the text around marks).*

```js
var filter = /<(?![/]?mark)[^><]*>/gi;

var regex  = /((?:(?!<[/]mark\s*>).){0,5})<mark\s*>([^<]*)<[/]mark\s*>(?=((?:(?!<mark\s*>).){0,5}))/ig;
var subst  = "$1 $2 $3";

var tests  = ['<p>Lorem ipsum mark> <MARK  >dolor</MARK > < mark sitamet. <mark>Lorem</mark> ipsum again and <mark>dolor</mark>.</p>','<P style="margin: 0 15px 15px 0;">um <mark>dolor</mark> sit amet. <mark>Lorem</mark> ipsum again and <mark>dolor</mark>.</P>','<p>um <mark>dolor</mark> <span>sit</ span> <test amet. <mark>Lorem</mark> <b>i</b>psum again and <mark>dolor</mark>.</p>','<p style="margin: 0 15px 15px 0;" another_tag="123">Lorem ipsum <MARK  >dolor</MARK > sit <mark>amet.</mark><mark>Lorem</mark> ipsum again and <mark>dolor</mark>.</P>'];


while(t = tests.pop()) {

    document.write('<b>INPUT</b> <xmp>' + t + '</xmp>');

    var t = t.replace(filter,'');
    document.write('<b>Filtered:</b> <xmp>' + t + '</xmp>');

    while ((r = regex.exec(t)) != null) {

        pre = r[1]; marked = r[2]; post = r[3];
        document.write('<b>Match:</b> "' + pre + ' <mark>' + marked + '</mark> ' + post + '"<hr/>');
    }
}
```

---

### How it works

---

1. Filter out every tag that is not a `<mark>` or a `</mark>` tag (case insensitive and space relaxed according to what is accepted by `chrome` and `firefox`: the regex does accept also the variations `<mark   >` or `</mark  >` as valid tags but not `<  mark>` or `</  mark>`:

   ```
   /<(?![/]?mark)[^><]*>/gi
   ```

   <kbd>[Regex 101 Demo](https://regex101.com/r/tZ0kY8/7)</kbd>

   [image: Regular expression visualization]

   **NOTE**: this filter handles the single chars `'<'` and `'>'` correctly (with or without text after/before them).

   This behaves differently from a browser regard the opening tag char `<`: anything after `<someText` till the next valid tag will be removed (breaking valid html tags). I prefer do not do this way and treat an opening not closed `'<'` as a simple char.

   *e.g.*: `Some text <notAtag other text <mark>marked</mark>`. `chrome` or `firefox` will output `Some text marked` (with `marked` actually **not marked** cause the `<mark>` tag is been filtered out together with `<notAtag other text`).

---

2. Select the marked text and its context (till 5 characters)

   ```
   /((?:(?!<[/]mark\s*>).){0,5}) #* 0 to 5 chars that not belongs to '<mark\s*>' 
                                 #  the round brackets save them in group $1
   <mark\s*>                     #* literal string '<mark' followed by 
                                 #  0 or more whitespace chars then literal '>'
   ([^<]*)                       #* 0 or more chars that is not '<'
                                 #  the round brackets save them in group $2
   <[/]mark\s*>                  #* literal string '</mark' followed by 
                                 #  0 or more whitespace chars then literal '>'
   (?=((?:(?!<mark\s*>).){0,5})) #* 0 to 5 chars that not belongs to '</mark\s*>'
                                 #  lookahead (?=...) used to not consume them
                                 #  round brackets save them in $3

   /ig                           #* i: Case-insensitive, g: global search
   ```

   <kbd>[Regex 101 Demo](https://regex101.com/r/rG6gB6/9)</kbd>

   [image: Regular expression visualization]

   **NOTE**: The regex is smart enough to select 5 chars both from the previous and the next `<mark>` if is the case (e.g. `</mark>12345<mark>`, `12345` will be both `post context` of the closing tag and the `pre context` of the opening tag).

   In addiction the context selection avoid to select over `<mark>` tags so :

   - where there is two adjacent `...</mark><mark>...` tags nothing is selected as post/pre context;
   - `</mark>123<mark>`: only `123` is selected as post/pre context.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it using simple regex.

`[\w\s.]{5}` = for 5 characters before and after mark

`[^<]+` = match anything between mark tags

```js
var myText = $('p').html();
var reg = new RegExp("([\\w\\s.]{5})<mark>([^<]+)</mark>([\\w\\s]{5})?", "g");
var match = null, matches = [];

while ((match = reg.exec(myText)) !== null) {
    var match3 = (typeof match[3] == 'undefined') ? '' : match[3];
 matches.push( '[...] ' + match[1] + ' ' + match[2] + ' ' + match3 + '[...]');
}

alert(matches.toString());
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>Lorem ipsum <mark>dolor</mark> sit amet. <mark>Lorem</mark> ipsum again
   and <mark>dolor</mark></p>
```

match array has 4 elements.

First (match[0]) one has all the matches.

Second(match[1]) has everything that matches in first set of brackets.

Third(match[2]) has everything that matches second set of brackets ie between mark tags and

fourth(match[3]) matches 5 chars after mark tag

Comment: Why downvote? it gives required output.. gotta give some reasons :/

Comment: Unless the downvoter explains, I consider the downvote invalid, thus, giving you +1. Note that using a RegExp constructor is not a good idea if the pattern is not dynamic. Besides, you needn't escape the `/` inside the constructor notation.

Answer (score 1):

it can be done using jquery contents() function. We can select text fragments inside an element by specifying index. Please checkout the below code, i have developed a logic and implemented it.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  
  var marks=$('mark')//get all the mark elements
  var j=0;
  for(var i=0;i<marks.length;i++){
  
    var markText=marks[i].textContent  //get text from each mark element
    
    var content1=$("p").contents().eq(j).text()
    //alert("content1"+content1)
    content1=content1.substr(content1.length - 5)
    
    j=j+2
    var content2=$("p").contents().eq(j).text()
    //alert("content2"+content2)
    content2=content2.substr(0,5)
    
    var final="[...] "+content1+markText+content2+" [...] "
    
    //alert(final)//you can push this final result into array or something u want
  $('body').append("<br>"+final)
  }

})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<p>Lorem ipsum <mark>dolor</mark> sit amet. <mark>Lorem</mark> ipsum again
   and <mark>dolor</mark></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

I made it till this. You can do this way:

```js
var results = $("p").clone().find("mark").html("1").after(" ").end().html().trim();
results = results.split(" <mark>1</mark> ");
results = results.map(Function.prototype.call, String.prototype.trim);
final = [];
for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i ++) {
  if (i != results.length - 1)
    final.push(results[i].split(" ")[results[i].split(" ").length - 1]);
  if (i != 0)
    final.push(results[i].split(" ")[0]);
}
$("pre").text(JSON.stringify(final));
// alert(JSON.stringify(final))
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>Lorem ipsum <mark>dolor</mark> sit amet. <mark>Lorem</mark> ipsum again
   and <mark>dolor</mark></p>
<pre></pre>
```